# Finding a ranking from a rating field on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table that looks like this:

```
id (int primary)
name  (text)
rating (float)
```

I have a page showing *rankings* which looks like this:

```
$i = 0;
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY rating DESC");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
    $i++;
    print("$i: {$r['name']}<br>");
}
```

This shows teams in order of their rating, with a ranking.  And it works.

Now, if I'm given the ID of a team, how do I find their *ranking* without running through the loop like this?   A single MySQL query which returns the team's info + a numeric ranking indicating how far down the list they would be, if I had rendered the whole list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ranking you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as ranking
FROM teams t
WHERE t.rating >= (SELECT rating FROM teams WHERE id=$ID);
```

To get all the relevant info too, you can do:

```
SELECT t.*,COUNT(*) as rank
FROM teams t
JOIN teams t2 ON t.rating<=t2.rating
WHERE t.id=4;
```

This joins `teams` to itself joining on `t.rating <= t2.rating`, and so you get one row for every team that has a rating higher than or equal you.

The `COUNT` just counts how many teams have a rating higher than or equal to you.

Note that if there's a tie this will give you the lower rank. You can change the `<=` to a `<` if you want the highest.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
select * from (
  select t.*, @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
  from (select @rank := 0) as r, t
  order by rating desc
) as t
where id = 20
```